# foreach error laravel multiple checkbox store

Tags: laravel

I store a few checkboxes as array in Laravel, but I get an error on Foreach. Can someone help me?

in model

```php
public function setHandServiceAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['handservice'] = json_encode($value);
}
    
public function getHandServiceAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['handservice'] = json_decode($value);
}
```

in checkbox

```xml
<div class="form-check mx-3">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="1" value="کاشت" name="handservice[]">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1">کاشت</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check mx-3">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="2" value="کاور" name="handservice[]">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="2">کاور</label>
</div>
```

handservice is column of reservation table in database with value like this after store

```
["\u062a\u0631"]
```

and in view

```xml
@forelse($reservation->handservice as $hand)
  {{ $hand }},
@empty
  nothing
@endforlse
```

error

> json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

I used this article but I get an error when one of the columns handservie is empty **handservice in nullable**

> https://hackthestuff.com/article/how-to-store-multiple-checkbox-value-in-database-in-laravel8

Comment: I think you might benefit from reading this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to assign something in a getter.

```php
public function getHandServiceAttribute()
{
    return json_decode($this->attributes['handservice']);
}
```

Comment: `Undefined property: App\Models\Reservation::$handservice `

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked

in model

```
public function getHandServiceAttribute($value) {
      return json_decode($value);
}
```

in view

```
@if($reservation->handservice != null)
    @forelse($reservation->handservice as $hand)
         {{$hand}},
    @empty
     نا مشخص
    @endforelse
@else
    <p class="text-danger">انتخاب نشده</p>
@endif
```

thanks all